# Spring Boot Map with Map Key

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I am trying to create a

```
Map<String,Map<Map<String,String>,String>> properties2
```

as a configurable property with Spring Boot properties file.

I have been previously been able to get a :

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> properties
```

populated with

```
properties.[A].B=C
```

where A is the first key and B the second key with a value of C.

I have already tried

```
properties2.[A].[B=C]=D
```

which doesn't allow the later components to start although it doesn't throw errors

Does anyone know how I can populate the properties2 map correctly?

Answer (score 0):

you can nest properties as following

```
private final Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> namespace = new HashMap<>();


namespace.[foo].[bar].a=alpha
```

May be you have error here Map,String>> properties2

```
as you you're using Map<String,String> as as key try this instead Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>
```